# WARNING: Invalid input 'S': expected 'n/N' USING PERIODIC COMMIT

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to import à CSV via Neo4JShell on Neo4J 3.0.4.

This script worked on an older version of Neo4J.

Here's my script :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
"file:///my_file.csv"
AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH coalesce(line.VAR1,"") as var1
MERGE (i:myObject {var1: var1})
```

But I get this error :

```
WARNING: Invalid input 'S': expected 'n/N' (line 9, column 2 (offset: 247))
"USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000"
```

Any idea ?

I install the zip version, one powershell to run "invoke-neo4j console", and an other powershell to run de "invoke-neo4jshell -file "my_script.cypher"

Thanks.

Comment: does it work when run from neo4j browser?

Comment: The error message says "line 9". What's on the previous 8 lines? Is there an incorrectly terminated statement by any chance?